# BeautifulSoup returning messed-up arabic characters

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, utf-8

I am scraping an arabic website using `BeautiifulSoup` but the arabic characters returned are returned inverted and separate chars (pasting it here correctly encodes it so you have to trust me on that :).

The website charset is using `UTF-8`

```
<meta charset=UTF-8>
```

This is how I am parsing it:

```py
url = 'https://new.kooora4live.net/matches-today-1/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
```

Writing the requested HTML to a file with `utf-8` encoding correctly formats it in the file so it seems as it's an issue with `BeautifulSoup`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong or how to fix it?

....
Update:
Encoding with `utf-8-sig` also doesn't work.

Comment: You can post the URL or bytes so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Do not blame `BeautifulSoup` in your case, I assume you are using Windows where the default encoding `cp1252`, Could you try to save to file with `UTF-8-SIG` ?

Comment: @MichaelRuth I updated the question with the URL

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I am using Ubuntu if that matters and `utf-8-sig` also didn't work.

Comment: Did you encounter the problem with characters when inspecting data through your IDE / printing it to console? It happened to me once that a string appeared different inside an IDE.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example as it seems to work fine for me with jupyter + bs4 + requests

Comment: We can’t tell you what's wrong or how to get a correct result without seeing (a representative, ideally small sample of) the actual contents of the data in an unambiguous representation; a hex dump of the problematic byte(s) with a few bytes of context on each side is often enough, especially if you can tell us what you think those bytes are supposed to represent. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the page encoding to match its apparent encoding.

Try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://new.kooora4live.net/matches-today-1/')
page.encoding = page.apparent_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml').select("a")
print("\n".join(a.getText(strip=True) for a in soup))
```

This will print out:

```
الأخبار
أهم المباريات
جداول
ترتيب الفرق
ترتيب الهدافين



مباريات الأمس
مباريات اليوم
مباريات الغد

جمهورية التشيك7:00 PM0-0لم تبدأ بعدالدنماركبي ان ماكس 1احمد البلوشييورو 2020
اوكرانيا10:00 PM0-0لم تبدأ بعدإنجلترابي ان ماكس 1حسن العيدروسيورو 2020

and more ...
```